# Lemmatizing with Spacy and Pyspark

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, spacy, lemmatization, pyspark

I have created a function to lemmatize a Pyspark DataFrame column.
Here is the code:

```
def custom_lemmatizer(df,input_col, output_col) -> DataFrame:
  """
      Lemmatizes the df's using input_column and returns
      a df with lemmatized words as output_column
  """
  input_col = udf(lambda x: " ".join(x))(df[input_col])
  def spacy_lemma(input_col)->list:
    nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
    doc = nlp(input_col)
    return [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

  spacy_udf = udf(lambda string: spacy_lemma(string), ArrayType(StringType()))
  return df.withColumn(output_col, spacy_udf(input_col))
```

The problem is that when I test it, it works after around two minutes whereas if I run it in the main function with other operations such as Vectorization, Stopword removal etc; The main runs forever. It seems like it disturbs the whole process. I am confident that the main is perfectly fine as it executes other tasks efficiently. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have `spacy.cli.download("en")` inside your function call.  This is to download the model and should only be done once at install.  The `spacy.load(..` is all you need.

Comment: Thanks, bivouac0, I do not think the problem is caused by that because the same thing happens even after removing ```spacy.cli.download("en")```. I have edited the snippet in the question.